# How to serve InMemoryStorage media files during Django tests

Tags: django, django-testing

I have some Selenium-based integration tests (subclassed under `django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase`) for my Django app that require a functioning user-uploaded media configuration. I've been using S3 storage (`django_s3_storage.storage.S3Storage` from [etianen/django-s3-storage](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage)) and that works just fine, but it incurs S3 costs each time I run my tests, plus the network overhead of going out to S3 is a lot during some of my media-heavy tests.

The newly added (in Django 4.2) [`InMemoryStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/files/storage/#the-inmemorystorage-class) solves both of these problems (S3 costs and overhead) perfectly, but I can't get the test server to actually serve the uploaded media files. I've added:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to my `urlpatterns.py`, but that has no effect since [Django tests are always run with `DEBUG=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions).

But even if I force it in to my `urlpatterns` by inlining the relevant portion of `django.conf.urls.static.static` like so:

```
import re
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(
        r"^%s(?P<path>.*)$" % re.escape(settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip("/")),
        serve,
        kwargs={"document_root": settings.MEDIA_ROOT},
    ),
]
```

it still doesn't work since [the `serve` function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e99c7d8847e9006f877ab3cea47f1977652af71f/django/views/static.py#L27-L63) looks like it's not storage-aware; it only works with media files on the filesystem.

The result is that my media files all return 404s when my Selenium browser requests them.

Is there a storage-aware equivalent to `django.views.static.serve` that I can use to serve my `InMemoryStorage` files during testing?

Comment: The InMemoryStorage wouldn't be shared between multiple processes, for one... I would probably recommend a regular disk storage, but backed by a tmpfs.

Comment: I'm not running with `--parallel`, but yeah maybe a disk storage + tmpfs is an easier option... Would be nice to not have to worry about setting up the tmpfs in the different environments (local vs. github actions, etc.) but still might be simpler than getting this to work...

Comment: TBH I don't think you're paying that much of a perf price with local storage, so since you're assuming the S3 storage works just like any other storage (e.g. InMemoryStorage) I'd just use a local disk-based storage in tests and [don't worry about it](https://i.imgur.com/BnTDwT2.png).

Comment: Haha true enough... Taking your advice though still interested in how `InMemoryStorage` is meant to be used for testing, if only now out of sheer curiosity!

Comment: All I can find for context is https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34110 and the PR implementing this, https://github.com/django/django/pull/16262